# Problems trying to explode a string

Tags: php, forms, post, explode

I am trying to split a text into an array using explode, but for some reason that does not work when the text is coming from a posted form.

If I run `explode('|§|', 'qwe|§|asd|§|zxc');` I will get an array like:

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => qwe  
    [1] => asd  
    [2] => zxc  
)
```

**BUT**

If this input text comes from a form define like:

```
<form method="post">
Input: <input type="text" name="query" size="50" value="qwe|§|asd|§|zxc"><input type="submit" value="Parse">
</form>
```

I am getting the following array:

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => qwe|§|asd|§|zxc  
)
```

Im guessing this has to do with iso settings and that the text in the 'query' field has been altered in some way, but I can't understand how to fix. I have tried setting `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />` and other charsets, but to no avail.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using to explode the content with

Comment: No offense, but any reason why you chosed such horrible value syntax?

Comment: None taken :) Two reasons Henrik, one is that this was quick to type because it's on the same letter for me in Norway, and because I had to pick something that it was highly unlikely that anyone would enter into a sentence :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably mistaken on this, but `§` may be a unicode character, which PHP does not yet support. Thus, there may be some issues when transferring from the form to the script.

Have you tried changing it to something more... normal? Like if you did `qwe|~|asd|~|zxc` instead, or maybe `qwe|+~+|asd|+~+|zxc` if you're concerned about what somebody would enter

Comment: Seems you are right about the unicode thing, that character seemed to be the root of the problem. I switched it to ~ and now it seems to work fine. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Just an idea: The § sign is probably be converted to url format. Try urldecode() the string first.